# Constructor that take parameters as default

Tags: c++, constructor, default-constructor

My code is

```
template <class T1, class T2>
class MyClass
{

    T1 first;
    T2 second;
    public:
    //default constructor
    MyClass():first(T1()), second(T2()) {}
}
```

I want to have a single constructor which can take 0, 1 or 2 arguments (parameters as default). Here T1 and T2 can be both primitive as well as non-primitive types.

Comment: Well, what's the problem? Declare them in the parameter list.

Comment: how to set default values for non-primitive types in parameter list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace your existing constructor with this constructor:

`MyClass(const T1& t1 = T1(), const T2& t2 = T2()):first(t1), second(t2) {}`

Comment: That would conflict with the existing constructor

Comment: You should make that `explicit`.

Comment: But, I 'm wondering how and where the compiler place default T1 and T2 instance to be use as "const reference" ?

Comment: @alexbuisson: The compiler, when it sees that you did not provide the arguments will generate them for you. When the caller says `MyClass a` the compiler will transform that into `MyClass a{T1{}, T2{}};` (using C++11 syntax to avoid the most vexing parse. If the call contained both arguments as in `MyClass a(b,c);` the compiler will not do any transformation and no temporaries will be created.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
template <class T1, class T2>
class MyClass
{

    T1 first;
    T2 second;
    public:
    //default constructor
    MyClass(T1 fst=T1(), T2 sec = T2()):first(fst), second(sec) {}
};

int main()
{
    MyClass<int,int> c;
    MyClass<int,int> d(5);
    MyClass<int,int> e(5,10);
}
```

You have to just assign the default value in the definition. You have to be careful that default arguments are always the last in the list of arguments. And that one constructor is all that's needed in all the situations of 0, 1 or 2 arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Default parameters can be use in constructor initializer list as for all other functions.

```
 MyClass(T1 t1 = T1(), T2 t2 = T2()) : first(t1), second(t2) {}
```